# How to remove an item from an array of localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've set few localstorage in my site with different names.
namely:

```
localstorage.setItem('one');
localstorage.setItem('two');
//console.debug(localstorage.getItem('two'));[2,5,6]
```

Now, the `localstorage.two` is array. How to remove a value from this particular localstorage?

I tried:

```
localstorage.removeId(2);
localstorage.removeId('two',2);
```

Comment: You'll need to `getItem` on your array, remove your value, then `setItem` back to the modified array.

Answer (score 2):

In localStorage can not be saved Arrays. So we need use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify.

```
localStorage.setItem("arr",JSON.stringify(["value1","value2"]));

//get element

var element1=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arr"))[0];

console.log(element1);

//remove element

var arr=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("arr"));
arr.splice(0,1);//remove first

localStorage.setItem("arr",JSON.stringify(arr));
```